# Editing Grid Cells with Coded UI Tests

Tags: devexpress, coded-ui-tests, xtragrid

I am trying to create coded ui automated tests; but i have problems with grids..

We are using DevExpress suit and i know DevExpress currently doesn't support Coded UI tests. However, i successfully capture controls; but i couldn't make editable cells on test playback.

My grid has two columns and three rows. First column is description column and the other column is value column.

Here is list of my capture approaches.

**1**

Approach: I clicked first row's value cell and wrote something

Result: On playback, computer try to click on first column, so it fails.

**2**

Approcach: I clicked row's header and press f2 then wrote something

Result: on playback, computer click on row header but nothings happen after that, so it fails.

**3**

Approach: I clicked value cells in order and returned back to first row by clicking on description cell than i pressed F2 and wrote something

Result. On playback, computer click on cells in order but nothings happen after that, so it fails.

How can i edit value cells in my coded ui test?

This test is created from manuel test's action recordings and there are there iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devexpress does not support coded ui tests yet.
But they say they're working on it.

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q265723.aspx

Comment: JFYI: [Implemented in 2012](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q252891). More info here:  [Coded-UI](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Coded-UI/)